# handle saving of transient gen_servers states when using a key-to-pid mechanism

Tags: erlang, concurrent-programming, autosave, gen-server

I would like to know how to handle saving of transient gen_servers states when they are associated with a key.

To associate keys with processes, I use a process called pidstore. Pidstore eventually start processes.
I give a Key and a M,F,A to pidstore, it looks for the key in global, then either returns the pid if found or apply MFA (which must return {ok, Pid}), registers the Pid with the key in global and returns the Pid.

I may have many inactive gen_servers with a possibly huge state. So, i've set the handle_info callback to save the state in my database and then stops the process. The gen_servers are considered transient in their supervisor, so they won't be restarted until something needs them again.

Here starts the problems : If I call a process with its key, say {car, 23}, during the saving step of handle_info in the process which represents {car, 23}, i'll get the pid back as intended, because the process is saving and not finished. So i'll call my process with gen_server:call but i'll never have a response (and hit default 5 sec. timeout) because the process is stopping. (PROBLEM A)

To solve this problem, the process could unregister itself from global, then save its state, then stop. But if I need it after it's unregistered but before save is finished, I will load a new process, this process could load non-updated values in the database. (PROBLEM B)

To solve this again, I could ensure that loading and saving in the db are enqueued and can not be concurrent. This could be a bottleneck. (PROBLEM C)

I've thinking about another solution : my processes, before saving, could tell the pidstore that they are busy. The pidstore would keep a list of busy processes, and respond 'busy' to any demand on theese keys.
when the save is done, the pidstore would be told no_more_busy by the process  and could start a new process when asked a key. (Even if the old process is not finished, it's done saving so it can just take his time to die alone).

This seems a bit messy to me but it feels simpler to make several attemps to get the Pid from the key instead of wrapping every call to a gen_server to handle the possible timeouts. (when the process is finishing but still registrered in global).

I'm a bit confused about all of theese half-problems and half-solutions. What is the design you use in this situation, or how can I avoid this situation ?

I hope my message is legible, please tell me about english errors too.

Thank You

Comment: I wanted to answer this, but didn't know where to start. Basically I want to say is try to avoid register processes on your own. it will cause a lot of complexity. simple start_link will spawn a process and when it finishes it will let the starter know it exits. If you go more than that, i.e. registering processes and controlling on your own, you can build it, but it will be a nightmare to maintain it. How about using a ets and each gen_server spawned lookup the ets and quit if running conditions not met? don't know what you are trying to do, so I can't give you the answer.

Comment: @bighostkim I thought Id-to-Pid tables were common in erlang applications ! Basically, the gen_server will check for running conditions, but there is a possible race condition. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to do the save to DB part in a `gen_server:call`. That would prevent other calls from coming in while you are writing to DB.

Generally it sounds to like you have created a process register. You might want to look into gproc (https://github.com/uwiger/gproc) which does a very good job at that if you want register locally. With gproc you can do exactly what you described above, use a key to register a process. Maybe it would be good enough if you register with gproc in your `init` function and unregister when writing to DB. You could also write to DB in your `terminate` function.

Comment: I believe that whatever i use (handle_call as you advises, or handle_info), the problem remains the same : the process is still able to receive calls at the time where it is going to shut down. I could use my pidstore on top of gproc, actually it's just a helper, global seemed easier, but i may replace it with gen_proc later. thank you

Comment: finally i found my way. It's simple : on timout, the gen_servers saves in DB then send a notification to the registry (« i am idle »). When the registry get this cast, it calls synchronoulsy the gen_server and asks « still idle ? », if yes, the registry kills it. Since the registry can't anwser calls during this procedure, if someone wants the pid for a particular id terminating, it must wait for this gen_server to be killed then the registry will start it again.

Answer (score 0):

For now i decided to stick with erlang « let it crash » philosophy. If a process recieves messages as it is shuting down, those messages will not be answered and will trigger a gen_server:call/* timeout.

I think it will be boring to handle this timeout in the right place, i have not decided where at this time, but this is specific to my application so it is pointless here.